# how to access a property of an interface in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this interface, I would like to access its ID property, from another component

```
export interface IItem {
 id: number;
 status: any;
peso: number;
medidas: any;
quantidade: number;
tabela: {
itemTabela_id: number;
item_id: number;
vPromo: number;
vPromoData: any;
vVenda: number;
};
estoque: {
estAtual: number;
item_id: number;
};
item_linkWeb: any;
descricao: string;
fotos: Array<string>;

}
```

how could I access her object ID for example?

```
test(){
console.log(item: IItem)
}
```

in this part of the code it shows the output of the normal item, item by item, the function `updateQuantidade` returns the normal item.id in the console

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of cartS.cart.item; let i = index">
            <td>
              <figure class="media">
                <div class="img-wrap" *ngIf="item.fotos">
                  <img src="https://esal.api.alleshub.com.br/images/erp_{{layout}}/item/{{
                      item.fotos[0]
                    }}.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-sm" alt="{{item.item_linkWeb.linkWeb.titulo}}" />
                </div>
                <figcaption class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="title text-truncate" style="max-width: 350px;">
                    {{ item.item_linkWeb.linkWeb.titulo }}
                  </h6>
                  <!-- <dl class="dlist-inline">
                    <dt>Variação:</dt>
                    <dd>G</dd>
                  </dl>
                  <dl class="dlist-inline">
                    <dt>Cor:</dt>
                    <dd>Vermelha</dd>
                  </dl> -->
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-top: 1.2em">

              <div>
                    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="quantidade" (ngModelChange)="updateQuantidade(item)" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="{{this.item.estoque.estAtual}}"/>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="price-wrap">
                <var class="price">{{
                  (item.tabela.vPromo || item.tabela.vVenda) *
                  item.quantidade | currency: "BRL"
                  }}</var>
                <small class="text-muted">({{
                  item.tabela.vPromo || item.tabela.vVenda
                  | currency: "BRL"
                  }}
                  cada)</small>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <!-- <a data-original-title="Salvar na lista de desejos" title="" href="" class="btn btn-outline-success"
                data-toggle="tooltip">
                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a> -->
              &nbsp;
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#modalConfirmDelete" (click)="excluirItemCart(i)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

The updatequantidade

```
updateQuantidade( item: IItem) {
console.log(item)
console.log(item.id)
if (this.quantidade > item.estoque.estAtual) {
  this.quantidade = item.estoque.estAtual;
  this.modalS.createModal(MdAlertComponent, { title: 'Estoque insuficiente', message: `Só há ${item.estoque.estAtual} unidade(s) deste item em estoque` });
}
const index = this.cartS.cart.item.indexOf(item);
this.cartS.cart.item[index].quantidade = this.quantidade;
this.cartS.updateItem(item);
}
```

but in this other function that doesn't have the ngFor="let item of cartS.cart.item; let i = index">, it always returns undefined

```
            <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Calcular o Frete</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input [(ngModel)]="cep" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" class="form-control"
                name="" placeholder="Digite o CEP" />
              <span class="input-group-append">
                <button (click)="getFreteByCep(cep,item)" [ngClass]="{'d-none': (loadingCep)}"
                  class="btn btn-success">Verificar</button>
                <div class="spinner-border" [ngClass]="{'d-none': (!loadingCep)}"
                  style="width: 2rem; height: 2rem;margin-left:5px;margin-top: 2px;"></div>
              </span>
            </div>
            <span class="small text-muted float-right mt-2 cursor-pointer" (click)="openMdNaoSeiCep()"><u>Não sei o CEP</u></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tem um cupom?</label>
            <span *ngIf="cupomAplicado" class="float-right text-danger cursor-pointer" (click)="retirarCupom()">Retirar cupom</span>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input style="height: 40px"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Código do cupom"
                [(ngModel)]="codCupom"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                [disabled]="cupomAplicado"
              />
                <div class="input-group-append cursor-pointer">
                    <span class="input-group-text py-1 justify-content-center text-light" [ngClass]="{'bg-success': (!loadingCupom)}" style="width: 62px; height: 40px;">
                        <a (click)="aplicarCupom()" [ngClass]="{'d-none': (loadingCupom)}">Aplicar</a>
                        <div class="input-group-text spinner-border" [ngClass]="{'d-none': (!loadingCupom)}" style="width: 2rem; height: 2rem;"></div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
 getFreteByCep(cep,item: IItem   ) {
console.log(item)
console.log(item.id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface does not hold values by itself. Rather it defines the type of the reference that points to the actual value.

You could do something like:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    private item: IItem;

    public test(): void {
        console.log(this.item);
        console.log(this.item?.status);
    }
}
```

But unless you actually set a value to your variable, all you are going to see is `undefined`.

Comment: I updated my answer friend, I think
let item of cartS.cart.item; let i = index
not letting the other function return the array of items

Answer (score 0):

Now, your `item` has the shape of the interface called `IItem`. To access the properties you need just to do something like:

```
item?.id
item?.tabela?.item_id
```

The `?` mark is called the optional chaining operator and it is used to prevent runtime errors against undefined properties.

Comment: I updated my answer friend, I think
let item of cartS.cart.item; let i = index
not letting the other function return the array of items